# How to post an event using IPC EventBus?

Tags: java, android, event-bus

I am following the answer on this post [IPC in Android using GreenRobot eventbus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188426/ipc-in-android-using-greenrobot-eventbus/39566781#39566781) about IPCEventBus.

```
public class Listener implements IIpcEventBusConnectionListener, IIpcEventBusObserver {

    public Listener() {
        IIpcEventBusConnector connector =
            ConnectorFactory.getInstance().buildConnector(context, this, "com.blueengine.login");
        connector.startConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(IIpcEventBusConnector connector) {
        connector.registerObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(IEventIpc event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(IIpcEventBusConnector connector) {

    }
}
```

Then on my **Login** app

I want to send an event called **UserLoggin**. How do I do this?

```
public class UserLoggin implements IEventIpc
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your event triggers post the event by calling this:

```
IpcEventBus.getInstance().postEvent(event);
```

As outlined in the [documentation](https://github.com/NewtronLabs/ipceventbus).